# Int Array left rotation from given index in c#

Tags: c#, arrays, rotation

The Array example is {4, 5, 3, 6, 1}
The user will input the index number and the array will be rotated left from the given index number.
Example: If the user input(index number) is 2, the result is: 3 6 1 4 5.

Any better approach?

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{          
    int[] a = { 4, 2, 8, 3, 1 };
    int l = a.Length;
    int[] b = new int[l];
    int x = 0;
    x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());
    int i = 0;
    for (int j = x; j < l; j++)
    {

        b[i] = a[j];
        i++;
    }
    for (int k = 0; k < x; k++)
    {
        int v = a[k];
        b[i] = a[k];
        i++;
    }
    for (int m = 0; m < b.Length; m++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}, ", b[m]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```

Comment: As this seems to be a homework, please show us what have you tried in order to solve it and what's the problem, so we can help better.

Comment: Already I've solved this with the given code but I need more dynamic and optimized code.

Comment: kindly, Which given code do you mean?

Comment: please check it bellow as I posted as an answer

Answer (score 0):

I will use this method

```
public static int[] CircularShiftLeft(int[] arr, int shifts)
{
    var dest = new int[arr.Length];
    Array.Copy(arr, shifts, dest, 0, arr.Length - shifts);
    Array.Copy(arr, 0, dest, arr.Length - shifts, shifts);
    return dest;
}
```

Usage in your code, i didnt changed the naming

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    int[] a = { 4, 2, 8, 3, 1 };

    int x = 0;
    x = Convert.ToInt32(Console.ReadLine());

    var b = ShiftLeft(a, x);

    for (int m = 0; m < b.Length; m++)
    {
        Console.Write("{0}, ", b[m]);
    }

    Console.ReadKey();
}
```